# fstab won't work

Tags: ubuntu, fstab

The fstab listed below gives a bad fs on boot.  The two enteries above the swap file entry are new.  The partitions are valid and worked with previous swap file by mounnting them after boot using the left pane of nemo.

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p9 during installation
UUID=00927e71-7570-470f-9eb5-3af1d5247385 /               ext4    errors=remoun\
t-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p2 during installation
UUID=C60D-9EBB  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# /media/john/Mydocuments on /dev/nvme0n1p6
UUID=15FA-4139  /media/john/MyDocuments  exfat  dirsync,nodev,windows_names,nos\
uid,noatime,async,timeout=2,uid=1000,gid=1009,fmask=0002,dmask=0002    0     0
# /media/john/MyChemistry on /dev/nvme0n1p7
UUID=15FA-19C0  /media/john/MyChemistry  exfat  dirsync,nodev,windows_names,nos\
uid,noatime,async,timeout=2,uid=1000,gid=1009,fmask=0002,dmask=0002    0     0
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw           \
   0       0
```

Error messages are: "exfat Unknown Parameter "windows_names" for both lines with the two exfat partitions that I am trying to mount.

SSD is GPT not MBR and UUID's are from gnome-disk-utility 42.0

Comment: Please edit the post to include the error message.

Comment: Do you really have a backslash and a newline in the middle of those lines in the file?

Comment: UUIDs are 128-bit numbers. How is your system finding file systems with a 8 character UUID?

Comment: What's the exact and complete error message?

Comment: @doneal24 you mean the EFI one? I need one like that on my systems too

Comment: @doneal24 Filesystems of the FAT family (vfat, fat32, exfat) don't actually have real UUIDs embedded in them, so for those filesystems, the Volume Serial Number is used instead of a real UUID. NTFS filesystems will also show a longer hex string that does not follow the formatting rules of an UUID.

Comment: @telcoM You're right. I missed that these were FAT file systems. `UUID=` in fstab is somewhat misleading but understandable.

Answer (score 0):

The error message `exfat Unknown Parameter "windows_names"` indicates the version of the `exfat` driver in your system does not recognize the mount option `windows_names`.

`windows_names` seems to be a mount option for NTFS, not for ExFAT.